# What carbonaceous form would result from pyrolysing HMW hydrocarbons and powdered biochar together?

Tags: pyrolysis

I understand that charcoal/biochar are mostly "amorphous carbon," and that the production of graphite via pyrolysis requires using a <60% C feedstock that will exists in liquid phase during at least a portion of the pyrolysis heating.

However, if a stable (mechanically), mostly-solid piece of carbon were the only goal of the process, could a liquefiable feedstock be used to "wet out," and bind together powdered charcoal, or bio-char in a second pyrolysis/carbonization cyle? And if so, are there any resources where I could find information about the physical properties the resulting final product would display?